# Javascript to change bgcolor based on values in Age Column in html table

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. I have a table as below in HTML:

```
FNAME LNAME AGE
abc    xyz   40
sfd    qwe   70  
ght    tyu   65
```

I now want to color the background in Age column to Red, if the value is > 60 in any cell of Age column. I would like to achieve this using javascript. In the above example rows 2 and 3 under AGE column should turn Red. Appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks,
Siva Nagarajan

Comment: Have you tried anything? It seems you would benefit more from a tutorial.

Comment: Can you please share the html code so that i can write javascript code for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using jQuery. The jQuery code is self explanatory. It makes the value red whenever the age is more than `60`. You can manipulate it your way.

**Output**

[image: output]

**The Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.empdata td.age').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() >= 60)
      $(this).css({
        'color': 'red'
      });
    else
      $(this).css({
        'color': 'black'
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="empdata">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>FNAME</th>
        <th>LNAME</th>
        <th>AGE</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>qwe</td>
        <td class="age">70</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sfd</td>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td class="age">40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ght</td>
        <td>tyu</td>
        <td class="age">65</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all for all your responses. Appreciate your help.. I will now try to incorporate this into my code and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 with jQuery

```js
let tds = $('.age');

tds.filter((i, td) =>
  $(td).text() > 60).map((i, td) => $(td).css('background-color', 'red'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>FNAME</th>
      <th>LNAME</th>
      <th>AGE</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td class="age">40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sfd</td>
      <td>qwe</td>
      <td class="age">70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ght</td>
      <td>tyu</td>
      <td class="age">65</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In ES5 with jQuery

```js
var tds = $('.age');

tds.map(function(index, td) {
  $td = $(td);
  if ($td.text() > 60) {
    $td.css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>FNAME</th>
      <th>LNAME</th>
      <th>AGE</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td class="age">40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sfd</td>
      <td>qwe</td>
      <td class="age">70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ght</td>
      <td>tyu</td>
      <td class="age">65</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```